# "onclick" event not working in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, onclick

I have some SVG paths inside a div with an `onclick` attribute:

```
<path class="limbs" id="limb1" d="some coordinates here" onclick="open(1)" />
```

The `open()` function is defined in a seperate JS file, which is implemented just before the `body` tag (like the jQuery file as well):

```
function open(n) {
    $("#information").fadeIn();
    $("#info" + n).fadeIn();
}
```

`div#info1`, for example, is an information box inside `div#information`, a full screen semi-transparent black background (gives it a lightbox-like effect).

Everything works well using Safari. However, if I try it with FF or Chrome, the browser seems to load a new page when I click (which shouldn't happen) and it results in a blank screen with no source code.

Page can be seen here: [frank.schufi.ch/3dmapping](http://frank.schufi.ch/3dmapping)

Comment: You should not use `onclick`. Instead, it's better to use jQuery `.on` method.

Comment: In the 3dmapping.js file on line 29, you pass a function to the jquery object. Are you sure that's what you intended? Usually only dom-elements or css selector strings are passed to the JQuery object.

Comment: @KemHeyndels : `$(function() {..});` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() {..});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are some mismatch behaviors between browsers so this could be the why it happens
 and for the what, it seems to me other `open(n)` function is being called.
try change the function name, to let say:

```
newOpen(n)
```

see if it helps.

Comment: wow. I can't imagine it's as simple as that! thank you very much!

Comment: Amazing how Google led me here in one shot, going on "firefox onclick white screen loading". Thanks for saving my evening!

Answer (score 1):

As Haocheng commented, a more up to date way of doing this is making an event handler for clicking the path. You would basically reach the same goal having this jQuery snippet instead:

```
$('.limbs').click(function() {
    $("#information").fadeIn();
    $("#info" + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn();
});
```

I'm not sure if this will make a difference in the outcome, as someone pointed out it might have to do with the fact that you named your function `open()`, so it might. What I would suggest you trying if you're still having problems, is adding a `preventDefault()`, like this:

```
$('.limbs').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#information").fadeIn();
    $("#info" + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn();
});
```

This removes default behaviour from HTML. For example, if `.limbs` would be a attached to an `<a>` elements, it would prevent the standard behaviour of following that link. Then again, renaming the function to newOpen() might be enough as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<path class="limbs" id="limb1" d="some coordinates here" data-open="1"  />

$('#limb1').click( function (e){
e.preventDefault();
var n = $(this).data('open');
$("#information").fadeIn();
$("#info" + n).fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` doesn't seem to be a valid attribute of `<path />`. So the browser is likely not adding a listener to that event. Try wrapping the `<path />` element in an element that will fire an `onclick` event then putting your `onclick` on that element, or as some of the other answers here are advising, use jQuery to force a listener on that dom element and fire an event on click. You can likely `addEventListener` with vanilla js and accomplish this same thing without jQuery as well.